# Does every game have a chance of survival?

Tags: alice-in-borderland

Near the end of the first season, Arisu speculates that there was a way to win the game without anyone dying, although it's unclear whether he is thinking about the current game or the one in which his friends died.  Even if it is the former, that raises the question:  Does every game have some trick where all the players could survive?

After all, the person in charge of the games is clearly very sadistic, but they also seem to have a sense of fair play. The intermediaries will be killed if they reveal their role in the game, but they have been warned about this beforehand. The Game Master does not, for instance, kill anyone who watches the video that the two intermediaries made, even though all the evidence  suggests that they know nearly everything that happens and can seemingly kill anyone at any time. Of course, it is even more sadistic if everyone has a chance to survive but they go to their own deaths, or lead others to theirs, willingly, so one would think that would appeal to the Game Master.

There are games that *appear* to leave it impossible for everyone to get through. For instance, the very first game seemed to require two doors to be opened before the players had enough information to deduce the safe path. And yet, does it make sense that a mere level 3 game (of clubs no less, so teamwork instead of betrayal) would require a player taking on a 3/4 chance of dying, assuming the same player opened both doors? Similarly, the seven of hearts game seemed to require that all the players but one die. But if a ten of hearts theoretically allows everyone to live by cooperating and thinking critically, does it make sense that a seven of hearts obligates almost all the players to lose?

Even in the games that seem to be impossible for a certain player to win, there is sometimes a trick. For instance, what a coincidence that a team with a player who had an injured leg ended up in a game where it *seemed* as if they needed to run great distances to escape, but where in reality they just needed to wait in the bus. When at least some games are planned with an exceedingly subtle twist that allows victory, up to and including a motorcycle that just *happens* to have the right kind of fuel to let the players refuel the bus and catch up with anyone who did not realize the trick, it makes one exceedingly suspicious about all of them.

So does every game leave open the possibility for everyone to complete it (perhaps even including the intermediaries), no matter how remote the possibility that they will stumble upon the correct answer? Or does the Game Master take a different view of a fair competition: there can only be one?

Comment: The bus was not really a twist just really bad thinking I mean you need to travel you would think you would look for gas and a car that works

Comment: Except the thing is that there was *no* need to travel. They only needed to stay in the bus. The whole thing is quite sadistic, because everything is set up to make the participants think they need to reach some distant objective: it was a spades game, meaning physical strength; there were water bottles along the road, making people think they have a long distance ahead of them; the counter counts up, which on typical step counter would be distance traveled; leave a motorcycle with gas and fill the road with cars, making people think they need to use one of them to get to the end, and so on.

Comment: Of course, it is quite a coincidence that in a spade game, which normally *requires* physical strength to win (in theory), there is an easy way for even the member with a hurt leg to win. Despite the obvious sadism, it seems like the GM goes out of their way to give everyone a chance, according to their own twisted perspective. It's hard to know their motivations, but I think they may think it is unfair for someone to simply have no chance because they started off injured, for instance.

Comment: There are several examples in the manga where the winner is the last person standing--would you accept those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC there was a game where 2 groups of players were against each other one group had to kill the other group or the explosive collars they wore would detonate it is doubtful that everyone could have survived although I might not be remembering it right.

Comment: I mentioned that in the question, as well as the possibility that there was a twist that would have allowed getting out of it.

Comment: In fact, only one *player* could survive in that game... *seemingly*. But even the games that seemed to be contests of strength, or betrayal, or teamwork, almost always seemed to have some trick of logic that would allow everyone to survive—even those who appeared to have no chance. Like I said, for an extreme sadist as the GM seems to be, people dying needlessly would be far more entertaining.